# Adding list of object in struts2 using ModelDriven<List<Object>>

Tags: list, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I want to add a List of Receiptitem into DB using ModelDriven. This is action

```
public class AddReceipAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<List<Receiptitem>>{

private List<Receiptitem> receiptItemList;
public List<Receiptitem> getReceiptItemList() {
    return receiptItemList;
}

/**
 * @param receiptItemList the receiptItemList to set
 */
public void setReceiptItemList(List<Receiptitem> receiptItemList) {
    this.receiptItemList = receiptItemList;
}

@Override
public List<Receiptitem> getModel() {
    return receiptItemList; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
@Action(value="addreceipt",
         results = {
             @Result(name="success", location="/w_receipting.jsp")
         })
 public String Addreceipt()
 {
     List<Receiptitem> temp = new ArrayList<Receiptitem>();
     for (Receiptitem item : receiptItemList)
     {
         if(item != null)
             temp.add(item);
     }
     ReceipDAO receipDAO = new ReceipDAO();
     receipDAO.add(temp);
     return SUCCESS;
 }
```

}

This is jsp page: with name of textfield is property of Receipitem object

```
                              <tr>
                              <td><s:select id="product1" name="receiptItemList[0].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                              <td><s:textfield id="quan1"  name="receiptItemList[0].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                              <td><s:textfield id="price1"  name="receiptItemList[0].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                              <td><s:textfield id="total1"  value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product2" name="receiptItemList[1].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan2"  name="receiptItemList[1].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price2"  name="receiptItemList[1].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total2"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product3" name="receiptItemList[2].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan3"  name="receiptItemList[2].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price3"  name="receiptItemList[2].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total3"  value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product4" name="receiptItemList[3].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan4"  name="receiptItemList[3].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price4"  name="receiptItemList[3].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total4"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product5" name="receiptItemList[4].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan5"  name="receiptItemList[4].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price5"  name="receiptItemList[4].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total5"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product6" name="receiptItemList[5].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan6" name="receiptItemList[5].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price6" name="receiptItemList[5].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total6"  value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product7" name="receiptItemList[6].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan7" name="receiptItemList[6].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price7"  name="receiptItemList[6].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total7"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product8" name="receiptItemList[7].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan8"  name="receiptItemList[7].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price8" name="receiptItemList[7].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total9"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product9" name="receiptItemList[8].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan9"  name="receiptItemList[8].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price9"  name="receiptItemList[8].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total9"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:select id="product10" name="receiptItemList[9].product.idProduct" label="Category" cssStyle="width: 178px" list="allProducts" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="quan10"  name="receiptItemList[9].receiptQuantity" label="Category Name" size="30" /></td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="price10" name="receiptItemList[9].receiptPrice" label="Discription" size="30" /> </td>
                                    <td><s:textfield id="total10"   value="" readonly="true"/></td>
```

But it does not work and all Receiptitem in receiptItemList are null.

Comment: how does ReceiptItem class looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

`To use ModelDriven actions, make sure that the Model Driven Interceptor is applied to your action.`

[Reference](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html)